# Vtiger Crm sms notification to the client

Tags: vtiger

I added the contact in vtiger crm also need to send sms to the contact 
I had used smsnotifier in vtiger crm but while clicking on the contact in the actions the sms is not going.
How to rectify it

Comment: Check your SMS Provider Configuration. You must have a well configured sms provider to be able to send sms.

Answer (score 1):

You can send SMS to your Leads, Contacts, and Organizations. To send SMS to records in the listview,

- Click on the desired module. Eg: Leads, Contacts, or Organizations.
- Select desired records to whom you’d like to send SMS. You can select records by clicking on the corresponding checkboxes preceding the records.
- Now click on the More dropdown > Send SMS
- In the ‘Send SMS to the selected numbers’ popup, select desired phone number field to send SMS, and compose message in the text space available in the step-2
- Once you’re done, click Send

Your message has been dispatched to multiple recipients successfully. Moreover, you can also send SMS to individual record from the detail view of that record

If you want to use your custom sms provider, Here is an example of using spring edge sms gateway:

```
<?php
class SMSNotifier_SpringEdge_Provider implements SMSNotifier_ISMSProvider_Model {

    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $parameters = array();

    const SERVICE_URI = 'https://trans.springedge.com/api/';

    private static $REQUIRED_PARAMETERS = array(
        array('name' => 'apikey', 'label' => 'API Key', 'type' => 'text'),
        array('name' => 'sender', 'label' => 'Sender ID', 'type' => 'text'),
        array('name' => 'unicode', 'label' => 'Character Set', 'type' => 'picklist', 'picklistvalues' => array('1' => 'Unicode', '0' => 'GSM', 'auto' => 'Auto Detect'))
    );

    public function getName() {
        return 'SpringEdge';
    }

    public function setAuthParameters($username, $password) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function setParameter($key, $value) {
        $this->parameters[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getParameter($key, $defaultvalue = false) {
        if (isset($this->parameters[$key])) {
            return $this->parameters[$key];
        }
        return $defaultvalue;
    }

    public function getRequiredParams() {
        return self::$REQUIRED_PARAMETERS;
    }

    public function getServiceURL($type = false) {
        if ($type) {
            switch (strtoupper($type)) {
                case self::SERVICE_SEND : return self::SERVICE_URI . '/web/send/';
                case self::SERVICE_QUERY : return self::SERVICE_URI . '/status/message/';
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function prepareParameters() {
        foreach (self::$REQUIRED_PARAMETERS as $requiredParam) {
            $paramName = $requiredParam['name'];
            $params[$paramName] = $this->getParameter($paramName);
        }
        $params['format'] = 'json';
        return $params;
    }

    public function send($message, $tonumbers) {
        if (!is_array($tonumbers)) {
            $tonumbers = array($tonumbers);
        }
        foreach ($tonumbers as $i => $tonumber) {
            $tonumbers[$i] = str_replace(array('(', ')', ' ', '-'), '', $tonumber);
        }

        $params = $this->prepareParameters();
        $params['message'] = $message;
        $params['to'] = implode(',', $tonumbers);

        $serviceURL = $this->getServiceURL(self::SERVICE_SEND);
        $httpClient = new Vtiger_Net_Client($serviceURL);
        $response = $httpClient->doGet($params);
        $rows = json_decode($response, true);

        $numbers = explode(',', $params['to']);
        $results = array();
        $i = 0;

        if ($rows['status'] != 'OK') {
            foreach ($numbers as $number) {
                $result = array();
                $result['to'] = $number;
                $result['error'] = true;
                $result['statusmessage'] = $rows['message'];
                $result['id'] = $rows['data'][$i++]['id'];
                $result['status'] = self::MSG_STATUS_ERROR;
                $results[] = $result;
            }
        }else{
            foreach ($rows['data'] as $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $result = array();
                    $result['error'] = false;
                    $result['to'] = $value['mobile'];
                    $result['id'] = $value['id'];
                    $result['statusmessage'] = $rows['message'];
                    $result['status'] = $this->checkstatus($value['status']);
                    $results[] = $result;
                }
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }

    public function checkstatus($status) {
        if ($status == 'AWAITED-DLR') {
            $result = self::MSG_STATUS_PROCESSING;
        } elseif ($status == 'DELIVRD') {
            $result = self::MSG_STATUS_DELIVERED;
        } else {
            $result = self::MSG_STATUS_FAILED;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function query($messageid) {
        $params = $this->prepareParameters();
        $params['messageid'] = $messageid;
        $serviceURL = $this->getServiceURL(self::SERVICE_QUERY);
        $httpClient = new Vtiger_Net_Client($serviceURL);
        $response = $httpClient->doGet($params);
        $rows = json_decode($response, true);
        $result = array();
        if ($rows['status'] != 'OK') {
            $result['error'] = true;
            $result['status'] = self::MSG_STATUS_ERROR;
            $result['needlookup'] = 1;
            $result['statusmessage'] = $rows['message'];
        } else {
            $result['error'] = false;
            $result['status'] = $this->checkstatus($rows['data']['0']['status']);
            $result['needlookup'] = 0;
            $result['statusmessage'] = $rows['message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function getProviderEditFieldTemplateName() {
        return 'BaseProviderEditFields.tpl';
    }
}
```

Save above code as springedge.php in /modules/SMSNotifier/providers to use.

Answer (score 0):

Smsnotifier in vTiger is basically event based program which sends out an SMS after a registered event is triggered, in your case add a new contact. You need to check with the sms provider lpgs and configuration to figure out whats really going wrong. I honestly dont think there is any issue with smsnotifier. FOllowing are the questions you really need to check for 
Which third party sms provider are you using? 
Do you have sufficient funds to send out the sms? 
DO you have the sms template registered and approved by the sms provider?
Are you appending the country code properly as requested by the sms provider?